# Typo 3 Version 12 issue No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.mainmenuMobile"

Tags: typo3

I have getting an error.
-No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.mainmenuMobile"
#1540246570 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.login"

I try this

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
`<div id="mobile-brand" class="navbar-brand" tabindex="1">`
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.login"/>
</div>
```

But it is not working can you give solution

Comment: Where do you have this snippet from? "lib.login" must be defined in TypoScript. As it is not defined the error is given.

Comment: Probably, you have not added typoscript lib.mainmenuMobile, or typoscript file is not included in sys template

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you have to create a lib.login in your typoscript setup:

```
lib.login = TEXT
lib.login.value =
```

However, since it seems that you use this in a fluid template,
you might consider using such a structure here:

fluid

```
<f:security.ifAuthenticated>
    <f:then>
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.logout"/>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
         <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.login"/>
    </f:else>
</f:security.ifAuthenticated>
```

typoscript:

```
lib.login = TEXT
lib.login {
    wrap = <li class="login">|</li>
    typolink {
        parameter = {$pageUids.login}
    }
}
    
lib.logout = COA
lib.logout {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        wrap = <li class="login">|</li>
        typolink {
            parameter = {$storagePids.felogin}
        }
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = Logout
    20.typolink {
        wrap = <li class="logout">|</li>
        parameter = {$pageUids.login}
        additionalParams = &logintype=logout
        ATagParams = class="logout"
    }
}
```

config/sites/xyz/.config.yaml

```
settings:
  pageUids:
    login  : [your fe_user pid]
```

You might have a look at the documentation, too:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1540246570.html